# xslt 2.0 : Unable to select multiple values from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an incoming large XML 2 segments

1st segment. Raw Data as a segment
2nd segment. The data which should be passed is in the 2nd one.

I am running a loop on the 2nd one and checking if value of FIeld1 in 2nd segment exists on the first one.

Problem: There are multiple returns from the 1st segment against the Field1 in 2nd segment but stores as 1 field and i am unable to separate them as fields.

Below is the code when run against the Field1 in 2nd segment against the whole 1st segment produces 2 results and stores them as one field value.I want them to appear as separate XML fields.

Note: this works fine when there is 1 hit.

```
<xsl:variable name="CheckEmployeeExists">
<xsl:value-of select="../../PerEmail/PerEmail/emailAddress[personIdExternal=$EmpNumber]" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Example of how this generated the value looks like for multiple entires

```
<Personidexternal xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">801035 801035</Personidexternal>
```

What i want though is like this

```
<Personidexternal>801035</Personidexternal>
<Personidexternal>801035</Personidexternal>
```

Below is the code when run against the Field1 in 2nd segment against the whole 1st segment produces 2 results and stores them as one field value.I want them to appear as separate XML fields.

Note: this works fine when there is 1 hit.

```
<xsl:variable name="CheckEmployeeExists">
<xsl:value-of select="../../PerEmail/PerEmail/emailAddress[personIdExternal=$EmpNumber]" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Example of how this generated the value looks like for multiple entires

```
<Personidexternal xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">801035 801035</Personidexternal>
```

What i want though is like this

```
<Personidexternal>801035</Personidexternal>
<Personidexternal>801035</Personidexternal>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This construct is a bit of a code smell:

```
<xsl:variable name="CheckEmployeeExists">
<xsl:value-of select="../../PerEmail/PerEmail/emailAddress
     [personIdExternal=$EmpNumber]" />
</xsl:variable>
```

It constructs a document node with a single text node whose value is the concatenation of the string values of the nodes selected by the "select" expression (which is exactly what you are seeing).

Usually when people write this, it is much better to write:

```
<xsl:variable name="CheckEmployeeExists"
select="../../PerEmail/PerEmail/emailAddress
     [personIdExternal=$EmpNumber]" />
```

I can't tell whether that's true in your case because we can't see the code that uses the variable, and the choice of variable name is very unhelpful.

Can't tell you how to correct your code without seeing more of your code; but here is a guess:

```
<xsl:copy-of
  select="../../PerEmail/PerEmail/emailAddress/personIdExternal[.=$EmpNumber]">
```

Do bear in mind:

(a) declaring the type of a variable is always a good idea in XSLT 2.0: it establishes that the author, the reader, and the compiler are all on the same hymn sheet.

(b) using `xsl:value-of` is often a mistake, especially when it's the only instruction inside `xsl:variable` or `xsl:function`